# Liquibase from SqlFile to XML

Tags: xml, groovy, liquibase

I try use that [plugin](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-groovy-dsl) to generate from my SQLfiles one XML file. I can't find any example how to use. I add jar's file to class path and use Grab for download plugin still getting methos error. What is wrong with `changeSet` ?

```
@Grapes(
@Grab(group='org.liquibase', module='liquibase-groovy-dsl', version='1.2.2')
)

import groovy.io.FileType

databaseChangeLog {
    def dir = new File(".")
    dir.eachFileRecurse(FileType.FILES) { file ->    
           // println file
        changeSet(id: 'sql-file') {
            sqlFile(path: file.absolutePath, stripComments: 'true', splitStatements: 'true', encoding: 'utf8')
        }
     }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please outline what your absolute goal is?  The Groovy-DSL for liquibase is an _alternative_ for the XML syntax.  If you want to generate one liquibase migration _as_ XML _with_ groovy, you dont need that plugin.

Comment: I want to take all SQL files in directory and generate one XML file. For example in Folder test, have many subfolders where are SQLfiles. On the basis of this files want generate one XML file with - author, id and path to that file.

Comment: Then you dont need that plugin at all.  Use a MarkupBuilder instead

Comment: Could you show just in answer how to in `dir.eachFileRecurse(FileType.FILES) { file ->  ` use markUpBuilder ?